# Wanting to filter results in EE tags

Tags: ee2, php, tags, codeigniter

Busy developing some custom modules for EE.  Everything is going swimmingly, except I can't seem to find any documentation on how to filter results in my modules tags.

What I am looking to achieve is something like:

```
{exp:my_mod:my_func month="June"}
    ...
{/exp:my_mod:my_func}
```

My hope is to filter results here and only show results for the month of June, rather than doing this filtering in the .mod file.  Is this a simple thing to achieve of should I just do it manually on the back end (which would mean creating 12 separate modules)

Comment: You certainly shouldn't use 12 separate modules, that's for sure. Are you looking for way to specify the month in your template? Unless I am misunderstanding you, isn't that just a simple parameter you're handing off to your module?

Comment: Yeah, definitely the wrong approach to create 12 separate modules, thats why I ran to StackExcahnge for help! :)  I think it is a parameter to hand over, but not sure how I do that... (new to EE dev)

Comment: I am not a programmer, but I think `ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('param_name');` should do the trick. Have you checked out the docs at https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html ?

Comment: For not being a programmer, you just saved my life.  Was able to search fetch_param and implement a working solutions.  Thank you so much.  If you want to answer, I will mark as correct!

Comment: Cool! I've just put that in a reply, perhaps others might find it useful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a common function functionality of addons to use parameters, so there's an EE function for that:

```
ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('param_name');
```

Check out the [docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/index.html) if you need an example and more info.